# Rails dynamic relationship (Active Record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the need for a dynamic relationship.  For example:

The model `Commission` has one `Payor`.

A `Payor` is either a `User` or a `Carrier`.

As of now, the `Payor` model looks like this:

```
class Payor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :carrier
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However, the `Payor` will only ever have either the `carrier_id` or `user_id` set in the database, because the Payor is either one or the other (but never both).

Is there any way to set a dynamic relationship and use a field to designate the model it's related to?  I'm sure I could create a field called type, but I'd prefer to do this the "Rails way" if possible.

Does Rails have a standard for accomplishing something like this, or should I stick with what I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for `carrier/user`.